# reminder script to remove string from file

Tags: shell-script, delay

I have debian squeeze installed on my box. I have BIRD daemon to route traffic of particular IP. We add IP to `bird-route.conf` automatically from ruby script if traffic spikes up to specific range. I would like to know the possible ways to send notification of added IP to remove from `bird-route.conf` after certain period, for example say If script adds the IP in `bird-route.conf` file at 12.00AM so notification script should notify me after 48 hours to remove it. How can I achieve this ? shell, perl or ruby any of the scripting would work.

Comment: Ubuntu user here, not sure what is preinstalled on squeeze: notify-osd, zenity? Python version?

Comment: Also: I assume planned notifications should survive a possible restart?

Comment: @Jacob Vlijm : Nothing is preinstalled, except python 2.7.3 and can't we survive without restart ?

Comment: @JacobVlijm : I am using my box remotely, so graphical notification is worthless.

Comment: One idea would be to have your "add" ruby script fire off an `at` job to call a removal script of the same IP

Comment: and if `at` isn't installed, just run the removal or notification script after a `sleep 2d` (or `sleep 172800` if your version of sleep doesn't understand the `d` suffix for days).

Comment: @JeffSchaller : Thank you for your suggestion. It helped me. Could you please post this as answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One mechanism for "delayed action" in Unix is `at`. Some system administrators may disable its usage, but if it's available, it can help you solve your problem.

1. Your "add" script can add the IP, then fire off an `at` job that calls a "remove" script with the same IP as a parameter.
2. Once the `at` job runs, it should check the target configuration to see if the given IP is still there (I'm not sure if your situation allows for the same IP to be "added" twice).